# create white image with php

Tags: php, gd

I trying create empty white image with php, this s my code

```
$bg = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);

imagejpeg($bg,"test/myimg.jpg",100);
```

but this created black image and I want create white, please tell how to set image for example white color?

Comment: Why so many downvotes for this question??
It is just a normal, not to bad question??

Comment: Start here http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php. @DerWaldschrat probably because a little research on the part of the OP would provide him with the answer.

Comment: @vascowhite a little research on 99% of SO questions would provide an answer. Don't disparage people for not knowing things that are basic for you.

Comment: @ZoltanToth please don't tell me how to think, I'm quite capable of deciding for myself. I wasn't disparaging anybody, I was telling DerWaldschrat why I thought the question was being down voted. I also provided the OP with a place to start his research.

Comment: Related to one of the OPs [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11905742/693207) questions.

Comment: 'a little research' now leads here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$bg = imagecolorallocate ( $img, 255, 255, 255 );
imagefilledrectangle($img,0,0,120,20,$bg);
imagejpeg($img,"myimg.jpg",100);
?>
```