# Issue while setting white color in blank image: php

Tags: php

**Problem**

Below code is creating an image with background color black.

I was expecting it to put white color. Am I missing anything in below code?

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(600, 1000);
$bg = imagecolorallocate ( $img, 255, 255, 255 );
imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $bg);
imagejpeg($img, "myimg.jpg", 100);
```

**[I am following this accepted answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11914361/726802)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`imagefilledrectangle()`](http://php.net/imagefilledrectangle) use x1, y1 and **x2, y2**.

Try this :

```
imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, 600, 1000, $bg);
```

or have a look to [`imagefill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php).

Comment: any idea about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476053/warning-invalid-font-filename ?