# Warning - Invalid font filename

Tags: php

**Problem**

I get a run time error which says - Invalid font filename. I am using XAMPP in Window 8.1

It seems like I need to map any path of fonts folder present in the C:\XAMPP or please suggest.

```
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('sunset.jpg');
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
$font_path = 'font.TTF';
$text = "This is a sunset!";
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);
```

Comment: Does that file exist in the same folder as this script? If yes, try changing it to: `$font_path = __DIR__ . '/font.TTF';`. If it doesn't exist in the same folder, then add the absolute path to it.

Comment: Still same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the path using `putenv` :

```
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
$font_path = 'font'; // no .ttf
```

Have a look to http://php.net/imagettftext .

Comment: @Pankaj I think you have to split your string into multiples ones. Then writes them using several `imagettftext()` calls. If I have understand your question :)

Comment: I think the anwser is no. You have to split your string, compute the size of each, then write each string at the right position, with the color you want.

Comment: @Pankaj Like I said before. You have to compute the sizes and write multiple strings. But, I don't think it's the right place to talk about this :)

Comment: Can u please check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476439/set-multiple-text-colors-in-same-line-over-image-php

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting fonts for the `imagettftext()` you need to start the font name with a `/` otherwise `.TTF` will be added automatically.

> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename along a library-defined font path.

resource: [php.net/imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php).

So your font declaration should look like this:

```
// this is if your font is in the default GD directory
$font_path = 'font';

// default directory is set by
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
```

or you could specify the whole path to the font:

```
// font is in some other directory
$font_path = '/path/to/font.ttf';
```